# How to compile Java class with external library in Windows command line?

Tags: java

I have an assignment: Write a client program `Permutation.java` that takes an integer `k` as a command-line argument; reads in a sequence of strings from standard input using `StdIn.readString()`...

Here is my code:

```
public class Permutation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         String[] inputStrings = StdIn.readStrings();
    }
}
```

How to compile it in Windows command line?

I tried

```
javac Permutation.java
```

But got an error

> ```
> error: cannot find symbol
>     String[] inputStrings = StdIn.readStrings();`
> ```

I use IntelliJ IDEA, external library StdIn is added to the project.

Comment: Do you have `import` statements in your code?

Comment: I don't have an import statement for StdIn class, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't highlight anything that something is import needed.

Comment: Once the jar is added to the classpath, IntelliJ will offer to import the class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: Maybe the StdIn class is in the default package

Comment: killjoy i said i added jar file of the external library to the project. michaeak is right, StdIn class is in the default package and it's not necessary to import. Thanks for minus in reputation

Comment: I actually didn't downvote you. Thanks for wondering. But yes, the answer below will work.

Answer (score 3):

To compile it with the library you have to add it to the classpath. This is accomplished with the -cp argument followed by the library which contains your referenced class.

```
javac -cp StdIn.jar Permutation.java
```

To run it with command line, similarly use

```
java -cp StdIn.jar Permutation
```

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: I compiled, but after running the second command, an error occurs "Error: Could not find or load main class Permutation
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Permutation

Comment: Can you try `java -cp StdIn.jar;Permutation.class Permutation`?